# Is "learning" part of cognitive psychology?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, learning

in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_psychology),

> Cognitive psychology is the study of mental processes such as "attention, language use, memory, perception, problem solving, creativity and thinking."

I wonder if learning is also a mental process that cognitive psychology studies, although it is not mentioned in Wikipedia? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, cognitive psychology incorporates the study of learning. You can see this reflected in other sources that provide general descriptions of cognitive psychology, e.g.:

- http://psychology.about.com/od/cognitivepsychology/f/cogpsych.htm
- http://psych.rutgers.edu/co
- http://infed.org/mobi/the-cognitive-orientation-to-learning/

I'm not recommending these as especially definitive sources; these are just the other three of the first four hits for [a Google search of "cognitive psychology learning"](https://www.google.com/search?q=cognitive+psychology+learning).

However, cognitive perspectives on learning are not the only perspectives available in psychological theory (see also [radical behaviorism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_behaviorism)).

Comment: does learning belong to any of "attention, language use, memory, perception, problem solving, creativity and thinking"?

Comment: It's distinct enough to deserve its own category, but it certainly involves most (if not all) of those.

Comment: I'd even say this is actually a somewhat problematic omission on the part of Wikipedia...someone should probably fix that!